# SonarQube integration for scanning Xamarin.ios application

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, sonarqube, sonarscanner

I am trying to scan the Xamarin.ios project by sonarqube scanner. But not able to scan the project. Only html, js file which are in project are getting scanned. After using the commands. Can anyone worked on scanning Xamarin.ios project by using sonar scanner. Please let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: I have it running in several projects. You need to describe more thoroughly what you are doing, otherwise it will be hard to help you.